# Is There A Way To Append Deleted and Updated Data To History Table

Tags: sql, powerbi

Alright, so I am working on a project at work and I need to append data to a new history table every time the data in our other table is updated or deleted. However, we are getting access to our sql tables from another company and they only gave us read-only privileges and we can only view them through Microsoft Power BI and Excel.

So I wanted to see if there was any way of creating a trigger of some sorts.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

From your question, you are trying to do an [incremental load of data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-premium-incremental-refresh), to  be able to append new data to a table. Also you are looking to have some sort of archive process to a history table, via a trigger. Incremental loads are a Power BI Premium feature only. However for the way you want to move the data based on a trigger, this is not supported in Power BI.

I would recommend trying to get better access to the SQL, or use Excel to get the data, dump it into Excel/CSV files, then create a process to load the new file(s) and figure out the changes, using some other database/etl process, then output to a file/table the results that PBI can read from.

Hope that helps

Comment: Alright, that's what I figured. Thank you, appreciate the response.